# How to write references in a C++ proposal?

Tags: c++

I have read how to submit a [proposal](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal) , [N3370](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3370.html) but could not find the **format** on how to write references. If you look at [P0142R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0142r0.pdf) you will notice the references are very different.

```
[3] International Organization for Standards. International Standard ISO/IEC14882. Programming Languages — C++, 4th edition, 2014.

[4] Bjarne Stroustrup. #scope: A simple scope mechanism for the C/C++ preprocessor. Technical Report N1614=04-0054, ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21, April 2004
```

Questions:

1. What is "#scope" mean in #4 ?
2. Where can I find the complete way to write references ?

Number 3 format is *Organization.Standard Name(Or document name?).Title.Edition.Year*

Number 4 format is *Author.[What is scope?]:Title.Way to find document.Month/Year*

Comment: "#scope" is part of the paper title.... The paper is very easy to find online.

Comment: Actually if you look closely they are quite similar: *Author. Title. Version/Date*.